# Is version field on package.json being used by libraries dependencies (yarn, npm...)?

Tags: npm, version, package.json, yarnpkg

I've been having problems when trying to update custom libraries stored in a git repo targeting those libraries on `package.json` like:

```
"dependencies": {    
  "awesomeLibrary": "git+https://awesome-library-url.git"
}
```

If I go to `awesomeLibrary` repo and push new changes, there are sometimes where I don't get the latest version. I need to remark that I **do not** change the `version` field on the `package.json` of `awesomeLibrary`.

Can this behaviour be affecting `yarn upgrade awesomeLibrary` or `npm update awesomeLibrary`?

Cheers,
Javi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to publish `awesomeLibrary` package or want to reference it from another project by pointing `awesomeLibrary` field in package.json to the package's repo, then **yes**, you'll have to add the `name` and `version` fields.

Otherwise it's optional.

Check "**Configuring npm**" from npm's official documentation for more details: [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#version)

*Note from their documentation: "Version must be parseable by [node-semver](https://github.com/npm/node-semver)"*